# Programmatically send SMS message in Android App on tablet without telephony

Tags: android, sms

Trying to send a SMS message through my Android App on a device without telephony like a Tablet without user intervention
Api 23

Would like to either:

1) Find a SMS text program that I incorporate into my Android app to send SMS texts using a device that does not have telephony available - I have no idea if this is possible - have tried to write but haven't figured it out.

OR

2) use a SMS app from the Google play store

I have also tried to send through an app (Textme, WhatsApp, Skype) downloaded from Google Play. I don't seem to be able to fill in the TO field see the code below.   Lines that have the // have tried

```
            String strPhone = "92xxxxxxxx";
          //  Uri sms_uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + strPhone); 

           Uri sms_uri = Uri.parse("smsto:+92xxxxxxxx"); 
 //       Intent sms_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, sms_uri); 
          Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND, sms_uri);

            i.setPackage("com.textmeinc.textme");
           // i.putExtra("sms_body", "Greetings!");
            i.putExtra("sms_body", "Good Morning ! how r U ?"); 
            i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
         //   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"92xxxxxxxx");
            i.putExtra("address", "92xxxxxxxx");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi from me");

         //      i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, strPhone);
         //   i.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, "92xxxxxxxx");
        //     i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "(408) 555-1212");
        //      i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + strPhone));
             i.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + strPhone)); 
             i.setType("text/plain");
           // i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); does not work
             BT_debugger.showIt(  "textme" );
             i.putExtra("chat",true);
             i.putExtra("sms_body", "test");


         try {
           BT_debugger.showIt(  "textme sms found" );
             startActivity(i);
         } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            BT_debugger.showIt(  "textme sms not found" );
         }
```

Comment: If the device doesn't have telephony, it cannot send SMS messages.  I'm not sure about the issues you're having with the intent.

Comment: For the intent, the message fills in but I can't seem to get the phone number to fill in